# How to download file from gitlab project "uploads" via command line

Tags: curl, gitlab

I tried to use curl with a private token:

```
curl --head --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxx" -L "https://gitlab.name.com/<group>/<project>/uploads/<hash>/file.tar.gz"
```

but always redirects to login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was requested with [issue 55520](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/55520), now [issue 25838](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/25838):

> It's possible to upload a file using the api (`POST /api/v4/:project_id/uploads`) but there is no way to retrieve the uploaded files (it used to be possible using the Private-Token auth and the web route `/:namespace_id/:project_id/uploads/:secret/:file_name`)
>
> [Edit by @Andysoiron](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/25838#note_272514463): It seems to be still possible to retrieve the file using `/:namespace_id/:project_id/uploads/:secret/:file_name`

Andy added:

> . I tried to reproduce it locally by uploading a file using `POST /projects/:id/uploads` and then retrieving it using `GET /:namespace_id/:project_id/uploads/:url` (I took url from the response of the POST request) and it worked.

[Apparently](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/25838#note_296077265):

> You can't use a `Private-Token` for auth you need a `Cookie: _gitlab_session` because `GET /:namespace_id/:project_id/uploads/:secret/:file_name` come from the front-end.

So this is in progress, as part of [issue 197361](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/197361).